# How can I configure an asp.net Service Provider (Web Application) to use Sustainsys.Saml2 with OKTA as the identity Provider

Tags: asp.net, sustainsys-saml2

Looking at the documentation at https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/getting-started.html#asp-net-web-forms

It appears that Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule would be the way to go.

*"In many cases it should just be configured in the web.config file and work without any code written in the application at all"*

So, I have created a simple test asp.net web application and referenced Sustainsys.Saml2 (2.8.0) and Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule (2.8.0) in my Visual Studio project

The Web Site that I ultimately want to add SAML SSO to is an asp.net web application with thousands of pages inheriting from a master page.  I want it to use the OKTA login pages as the Identity Provider, but if I get that working I would try it on other Identity Providers too.

Unfortunately, I am finding the configuration settings bewildering.

Does anyone have a really basic (minimal) example web.config for Single Sign On for a basic SAML 2 application setup in OKTA (using mostly defaults)?

I can do stuff like downloaded the X509 .cert from the OKTA App Integration

**Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL:**
https://#######.okta.com/app/#######_sustainsyssamlexample_1/####################/sso/saml

**Identity Provider Issuer:**
http://www.okta.com/####################

**Single Sign On URL:**
https://localhost:44334/Saml2/Acs

**Recipient URL:**
https://localhost:44334/Saml2/Acs

**Destination URL:**
https://localhost:44334/Saml2/Acs

**Audience Restriction:**
https://localhost:44334/Saml2

**Name ID Format:**
x509SubjectName

I am assuming that the **/Saml2/Acs** and **/Saml2** are requirements that are built into Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule

I just need to get something working and then I can play around with the rest.  Any help on this would be brilliant.